# Why am I unable to access my files on my Nexus 4 from XP?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

My Nexus 4 is recognised as a Nexus 4 in Device Manager with a yellow exclamation mark on its icon.

When I installed the USB drivers for it, the yellow mark went away, and Device Manager said that the device is working properly. However, it is not appearing as a portable device or removable drive, and I cannot access the files on the device.

What am I missing? I'm running 32-bit Windows XP SP3 .

Comment: Did you switch the USB mode from charging to mass storage?

Answer (score 2):

As wrong as this sounds, you need to update your version of Windows Media Player in order to install the MTP drivers that are now needed for modern Android devices.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/download-windows-media-player

You can also download and install the [MTP kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=19153) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

After you install the USB driers go to "developer" section on your device and uncheck "USB debugging ! After that you will see the phones internal storage on your PC named, maybe "Nexus4" under "My Computer. Thats how i got to my files....